# sun.misc.BASE64 to apache commons

Tags: java, base64, aes, apache-commons

I have a simple code here, the code uses the sun.misc.BASE64Encoder and sun.misc.BASE64Decoder, which are not available in Eclipse Java 7.0 , I wanted to make the code such that it uses the Apache commons base 64 and still do exactly the same thing,

**The variables**

```
private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final byte[] keyValue = "2H5a1r5i6s3h8C1h".getBytes();
```

**Original Code**

```
public static String AESencrypt(String valueToEnc) throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGORITHM);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
    return encryptedValue;
}

public static String AESdecrypt(String encryptedValue) throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGORITHM);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedValue);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}
```

**Trying to modify to apache commons code**

```
public static String AESencrypt(String valueToEnc) throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGORITHM);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new Base64().encodeBase64(encValue).toString();
    return encryptedValue;
}

public static String AESdecrypt(String encryptedValue) throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGORITHM);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = new Base64().decodeBase64(encryptedValue);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}
```

The original code works fine, the new code throws the following exception,

> Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException:
>   Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
>     at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:750)
>     at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
>     at
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
>     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)    at
>   trial2.encrypt.AESdecrypt(encrypt.java:28)    at
>   trial2.encrypt.main(encrypt.java:37) 
>   Java Result: 1

How can I solve this problem without altering the initial code too much, a few lines here and there are OK. Is it possible to completely eliminate the Base64encoding step and make it work with only the ciphers like this:

```
public static String AESencrypt(String valueToEnc) throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGORITHM);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
    return encValue.toString();
}

public static String AESdecrypt(String encryptedValue) throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGORITHM);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(encryptedValue.getBytes());
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}
```

The above code has similar exception like the second code:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException:
>   Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
>     at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:750)
>     at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
>     at
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
>     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)    at
>   trial2.encrypt.AESdecrypt(encrypt.java:26)    at
>   trial2.encrypt.main(encrypt.java:35) Java Result: 1

Please help and TYVM

Comment: Suggestion: strip out the crypto and do some testing. Do they produce the same values, etc. This should be solveable!

Comment: Never *ever* use Sun internal classes, they may be removed or changed without warning. They are NOT part of the official Java API. Note that the classes become available again if you select a specific JRE or JDK instead of a runtime environment (again, because the runtime environment only uses those classes for implementation purposes, not as API)

Comment: Never just specify "AES" as algorithm, as it may return different defaults for specific providers. With the Sun/Oracle default it returns "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" which is unsafe to use (minimum required mode for confidentiality is CBC mode).

Comment: Never use the `getBytes()` or `String` constructor without specifying an encoding. With Java 7 you may use `String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF8)` instead. I'll let you guess the constructor call if you don't mind.

Comment: Never directly use a `String` value as a key, you should use a KDF such as PBKDF2 (search this site) if you want to use a password, or you should use a secure random binary key for encryption/decryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your encrypt method. The following code is wrong:

```
byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
String encryptedValue = new Base64().encodeBase64(encValue).toString();
```

You are calling `toString()` on a byte array, which won't do what you want! Instead, try:

```
byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
String encryptedValue = Base64.encodeBase64String(encValue);
```

This should then work correctly.

Comment: that seems to work, is it necessary to have a base64encoding step? i mean I dont understand what it does.

Comment: The base64 encoding step is one of the options available to you if you wish to store your ciphertext as a string. The other commonly chosen option is base16 (a.k.a hexadecimal). Depending upon your use case, you could just keep the ciphertext as a byte array. Normally a conversion to string is only for transmission of the data, especially in web environments.

Comment: ty for the help, Guess that I need to do it to save to Database.